# accepting different type of date format python 3 and calculate the difference

Tags: python-3.x, date-format

I'm extracting date from Nmap and sometimes the date format is different in a different system, how I can handle different date format. so far this how I'm doing it

```
  def calcualte_cert_validation(self, data, url):
        for value in data:
            if value["certificate-check"] == "Not valid after":
                certificate_data = self.verify_cert("Not valid after",url)
                try:
                    datetime.strptime(certificate_data, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') # certificate data is date from Nmap
                    cert_date = datetime.strptime(certificate_data, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S') #change date format in order to calculate the difference
                    current_date = datetime.strptime(datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S'),"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
                    diff = abs((current_date - cert_date).days)
                    return diff
                except ValueError:
                    print("INFO : Incorrect date format, should be %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S")
                    return False
```

is there a simple to do all this ? and handle different date format ?

Comment: I don't see the other date format. You need to give an example of what it looks like.

Comment: Incorrect date format, should be %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S, the date I'm getting from the server is different , how i can format any giving date to this one %Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S

Comment: You can't. You need to know the format of date that you are dealing with.

Comment: You can choose from multiple date formats and for this, you still need to know what are they.

Comment: I see, well I dont know the date format I'm getting, depends on the server! Thanks for the hint